# A Java Deck class

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code for a card game I'm making and I can't seem to make it output all the cards in the deck EXCEPT cards of rank `"A","2","3","8","J","Q"` and `"K"` (I dont want these ranks to be output). Any help please

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

public static void main (String[]args) {

    String[]suit = {"♣","♥","♦","♠"} ;
    String[]rank = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"} ;

    int SUITS = suit.length;
    int RANKS = rank.length;
    int N = SUITS*RANKS;

 // initialize deck
    String[]deck = new String [N];

    for ( int i=0; i<RANKS; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<SUITS; j++) {

            deck [SUITS*i+j] = rank[i] + suit[j];
        }
    }

 // shuffle
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

        int r = i + (int)(Math.random()*(N-i));

        String t = deck [r];
        deck[r] = deck [i];
        deck[i] = t;
    }

// print shuffled deck
    for ( int i=0; i<N; i++) {

            System.out.println (deck[i]);

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you print the whole of the unshuffled deck?

Comment: does your character system recognize your special characters "♣","♥","♦","♠"

Comment: Why don't your deck is not two dimensional array?

Comment: Seems to be working, what makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Guys, the code works just fine. The problem is that I need something like a conditional statement that will pick another card if the card chosen to start the game is of the rank "A","2","3","8","J","Q" or "K"

Comment: how about if(deck[x].charAt(0) == "A")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On possibility would be to check if the first card is an invalid card and then to discard it and reshuffle the deck if it is. Like Sara said above we would check the charAt index 0 and see if it is an invalid card. In the example below there is also a different method for shuffling the deck so that it can be accessed within the for loop. Left the stuff at the top out but give this a shot.

```
deck = shuffleDeck(deck, N);

// print shuffled deck
for ( int i=0; i<N;) 
{

    //checking for invalid char at index 0
    if(i == 0 && (deck[i].charAt(0) == 'K' || deck[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || deck[i].charAt(0) == '2' || deck[i].charAt(0) == 'Q'))
    {
         System.out.println("Invalid first card.");
         shuffleDeck(deck, N);
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println(deck[i]);
         i++;
    }
}
}

private static String[] shuffleDeck(String[] deck, int N)
{
    // shuffle
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        int r = i + (int)(Math.random()*(N-i));
        String t = deck [r];
        deck[r] = deck [i];
        deck[i] = t;
    }
return deck;
}
```